# Required Fields in Share Point data collection not throwing errors

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-designer

I have created a workflow in Share Point Designer on our MOSS2007 dev server.  (No one is allowed to have access to write .NET code yet as company policy)

In this workflow I am collecting data from the user, and both of my custom content types I created are marked as required, but the page isn't tossing errors when I don't supply values; not client side nor server side.

I checked the ..xoml.wfconfig.xml file and set the properties for required to true, I set the content type to required, and I used Share Point design to mark them as required.  Nothing.

This is a out of the box installation except for the master page and style sheets.  To make sure it wasn't that, I reverted to an out of the box style sheet.

Any ideas on what else to check / set?

Answer (score 2):

Sharepoint can be a bit quirky.  I followed [this guide](http://davidmcnamee.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=fb0f1146-befc-43b7-971b-9c4507a55031&ID=18) successfully to get required fields.  I'm not sure its quite the same thing you are trying to do, but maybe it will get you going down the right track.  Basically it uses Page Layouts and Content Types with to enforce  required fields.

I'm curious to know if this method is so much different from the way you are doing it

Comment: The Share Point Designer Workflow wizard does all that creation for you, plus ties it into the workflow.  It was good to see this link cause I could verify the steps I already did, but still no luck.